# A certain page will now show up after deployment in Azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I deployed a simple app through Azure from the Razor Tutorial I saw on the Microsoft website.  The home page shows up, but when I click on the link where the movie pages is, I get an error. I am currently in development environment, to see if I can get a more detailed message about what the error is, but I am not getting any details. Is there anyway I can find out what is causing that particular page to not work?  I checked on my Azure portal, and according to them, the deployment is complete with no errors.

[This](https://razorpagesmovie20190926093912.azurewebsites.net/) is the app I created through the tutorial

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) to the tutorial if you're interested in seeing what I was building.

Comment: You need to configure application insights for your website - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview

Comment: How did you deploy said app to Azure?

Comment: @DenDelimarsky I followed this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet

I started from the publish your web app section.

Answer (score 0):

I think the model is missing from your application:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Also make sure your app is running locally before deploying to Azure